# Stop VBA execution from DLL

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

In the process of converting an Excel VBA application to VB.NET I understand that I cannot use `End` statements inside the DLL because it should only be stopped by the process that started it. Instead, it seems that the DLL must raise an event to be handled by the VBA code in Excel.

I think got most of it working except the part where the raised event should be detected in order to stop the execution imediatedly. Here's what I got so far:

The DLL's procedure called by VBA:

```
Public Class Class1
    Sub DLLentry()
        Dim ClStop As New ClassStop
        AddHandler StopExecution, AddressOf ClStop.stopExec
        DLLprocedure1()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The procedure that executes most of the operations:

```
Module Module1
    Public Event StopExecution()
    Sub DLLprocedure1()
        'Operations that in certain circumstances must stop the execution
        RaiseEvent StopExecution()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The class that should comunicate the raised event to Excel:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
<Guid("28C7DCE1-90EF-4a30-AF7F-4187F9FFFDEB")>
Public Interface ICoreEvents
    <DispId(1)>
    Sub StopExecutionCl()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
<Guid("86CE5E8D-777D-4cd5-8A7D-7F58737F1DB4")>
Public Interface ICore
    Sub stopExec()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(ICore))>
<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ICoreEvents))>
<Guid("C58721B1-15B3-4eeb-9E1E-BCDA33D38EE6")>
Public Class ClassStop
    Implements ICore
    <ComVisible(False)>
    Public Delegate Sub OnStopExecutionCl()
    Public Event StopExecutionCl As OnStopExecutionCl
    Sub stopExec() Implements ICore.stopExec
        MsgBox("Checkpoint 1")
        RaiseEvent StopExecutionCl()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In Excel's VBA I have a module in the procedure that starts the execution:

```
Sub StartingProcedure()
    Dim oMyApp1 As New Class1
    Call oMyApp1.activateEvent

    Dim oMyApp2 As New DLLname.Class1
    Call oMyApp2.DLLentry
End Sub
```

And a class module that should capture the event and stop the execution:

```
Public WithEvents cls1 As DLLname.ClassStop

Private Sub cls1_StopExecutionCl()
    MsgBox "Checkpoint 2"
    End
End Sub

Public Sub activateEvent()
    Set cls1 = New DLLname.ClassStop
End Sub
```

The DLL "DLLname.dll" is registered as COM and referenced in Excel. I know that the event declaration inside the DLL is properly detected by Excel since I can select it from the dropdown menu on the class module.

The problem is that even though "Checkpoint 1" is reached several times (the event is raised), "Checkpoint 2" isn't reached.

What am I missing? Is this the best way of accomplishing what I want?

P.S. I'm not sure, but couldn't I supress the `Guid` definitions and the `Interface` `ICore`?

Comment: Not sure I'm following exactly since I've never done this, but isn't the DLL object instance `cls1` in your event-handling VBA class instance a different one from `oMyApp2`

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, they refer to different classes in the DLL. I tried to make it a single class, by moving the procedure `DLLentry` to `ClassStop`, thus eliminating `Class1`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Aren't they different classes in different *instances* of the DLL though?

Comment: @TimWilliams You are right. I was not quite aware of the concept of different instances. I replaced by `Call oMyApp1.cls1.DLLentry` and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code achieved with @Tim Williams guidance in the comments.

In the DLL:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)>
<Guid("28C7DCE1-90EF-4a30-AF7F-4187F9FFFDEB")>
Public Interface ICoreEvents
    <DispId(1)>
    Sub StopExecutionCl()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)>
<Guid("86CE5E8D-777D-4cd5-8A7D-7F58737F1DB4")>
Public Interface ICore
    Sub DLLentry()
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)>
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(ICore))>
<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ICoreEvents))>
<Guid("C58721B1-15B3-4eeb-9E1E-BCDA33D38EE6")>
Public Class Class1
    Implements ICore
    Public Event StopExecutionCl()

    Sub stopExec()
        MsgBox("Checkpoint 1")
        RaiseEvent StopExecutionCl()
    End Sub

Sub DLLentry() Implements ICore.DLLentry
        AddHandler StopExecution, AddressOf stopExec
        DLLprocedure1()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In a module:

```
Module Module1
    Public Event StopExecution()
    Sub DLLprocedure1()
        'Operations that in certain circumstances must stop the execution
        RaiseEvent StopExecution()
    End Sub
End Module
```

In Excel's VBA - class module `Class1`:

```
Public WithEvents cls1 As DLLname.Class1

Private Sub cls1_StopExecutionCl()
    MsgBox "Checkpoint 2"
    End
End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Sub StartingProcedure()
    Dim oMyApp1 As New Class1
    Set oMyApp1.cls1 = New DLLname.Class1
    Call oMyApp1.cls1.DLLentry
End Sub
```